# ant string manipulation : extracting characters from a string

Tags: java, regex, ant

I have an ant property which has value of the type 1.0.0.123

I want to extract the value after the last dot, in this case that would be '123'.
Which ant task should i use and how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok i have found the answer myself and this is tested.
you just gotta use a bit of javascript.

```
<target name="get build ctr">

    <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[

                // getting the value
                buildnumber = myproj.getProperty("build.number");
                index = buildnumber.lastIndexOf(".");
                counter = buildnumber.substring(index+1);
                myproj.setProperty("buildctr",counter);

            ]]>
    </script>

</target>
```

Answer (score 12):

#### With native ant task

If not wanting to use external libs nor scripting, I found in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135833/413020) the best option (credit him for this answer). Here you'll be using a [ReplaceRegex](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex):

```xml
<loadresource property="index">
  <propertyresource name="build.number"/>
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <filetokenizer/>
      <replaceregex pattern=".*\.)" replace="" />
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</loadresource>
```

<sup>(I have used the same variable names as you in your solution. Of course, this is still missing the increment part of your answer, but that was not in your question.)</sup>

This script loads in `index` the result of deleting the regex `.*\.)` from `build.number`, that is, if `build.number = 1.0.0.123` then `index = 123`.

---

#### Example

`build.xml:`

```
<project name="ParseBuildNumber" default="parse" basedir=".">
    <property name="build.number" value="1.0.0.123"/>

    <target name="parse">
        <loadresource property="index">
            <propertyresource name="build.number"/>
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <filetokenizer/>
                    <replaceregex pattern=".*\." replace="" />
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </loadresource> 
        <echo message="build.number=${build.number}; index=${index}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

```
$ ant
Buildfile: /tmp/build.xml

parse:
     [echo] build.number=1.0.0.123; index=123

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: The regex didn't work for me (I am trying to do the same thing but with an IP address).  I ended up with a pattern of ".*\." (Match everything up to the last period and replace it with "", right?  I'm an absolute regex newb).  This seems to give the result I was after (the last quad)

Comment: Oh also it wasn't obvious to me what this was doing--from the referenced source answer...  The propertyresource "build.number" is a variable containing your dotted string, the output is placed into the loadresource variable "index".

Comment: @BillK I have picked the same variable names as those used by the author of the OP [in his own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955150/413020). I'll expand my answer to clarify this.

Comment: @BillK regarding the regex, I must admit I don't know how come I came up with this... I would read my suggestion as "match everything, and then match anything but dots." This does in fact looks pretty wrong to me, whereas your suggestion does look right. I'll correct it. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I suspect the easiest approach may be to use the ant-contrib [PropertyRegex task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html).

Something like this - completely untested:

```
<propertyregex property="output"
          input="input"
          regexp=".*([^\.]*)"
          select="\1" />
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<propertyregex property="xtractedvalue" 
               input="${foobar}" 
               regexp="(.*)\.(.*)$" 
               select="\2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) without scripting =

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

 <property name="foobar" value="1.0.0.123"/>

  <target name="main">   
   <!-- simple echo -->
   <fl:echo>xtractedvalue => #{split('${foobar}','\.')[3]}</fl:echo>
   <!-- create property for further processing.. -->
   <fl:let>
    xtractedvalue := split('${foobar}','\.')[3]
   </fl:let>
   <echo>$${xtractedvalue} => ${xtractedvalue}</echo> 
  </target> 
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also use the ant-contrib PropertyRegex task.
The following snippet only works if the input string follows the convention you used in your description and you can also use it to extract the other numbers by changing the value entered in the select tag.

```
<propertyregex property="output"
          input="input"
          regexp="(\d)\.(\d)\.(\d)\.(\d{3})"
          select="\4" />
```

You can also use the issest task on the output string to print out an error message if the input string does not follow the convention, because the output property will not be set.