# Proguard with Duplicate Zip entry error

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

When I applied proguard, then in console ,getting below error.please solve my issue.

**solve duplicate zip entry error while applying progaurd.**

**Console Error:**

Note: there were 157 duplicate class definitions.

```
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-io-2.4.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [httpmime-4.2.1.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [httpmime-4.2.1.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
```

Anyone help me regarding this proguard problem? I have searched a lot in google, but still can't find any proper solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link before your warning explains your problem pretty straight forward... http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass

Comment: @alfasin i have read it.but in this doc,i don't getting any solution.

Comment: The solution is stated explicitly: filter out these resources from the included jars. In regards to "how to" do it, it depends on how you're building your project, rekire shows you below how to do it using Gradle. [Here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html) is a maven example, and if you're using anything else - it shouldn't be difficult to google it. Voting to close the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397717/ant-task-to-filter-jars-for-zip-file-and-manifest

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't write the details I expect that you are using Android Studio and Gradle as build system. Add to your android DSL this block:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude '.readme'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'README.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

You do not need all of them but it will work. This basically blocks the build system to include some files. In your case some useless text files.