# Ant add trailing zeros

Tags: ant

Hello i have a variable in Ant: `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`
And i wan't that this variable is always 6 characters long.
If not Ant should add trailing zeros.

1 should be 100000
39 should be 390000
5656 should be 565600

How is this possible using a Ant build script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution using the [PropertyFile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) Ant task described here: [Re: Zero-Padding an Int Ant Property](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200608.mbox/%3C20060825000008.9390@gmx.net%3E)

You may also want to checkout the [propertyregex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) task from [Ant Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). See [Replacing characters in Ant property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176071/replacing-characters-in-ant-property/1176101#1176101)

Comment: thanks for the `Zero-Padding an Int Ant Property` link ... worked perfectly for me.