# ANT: separate folder list by comma

Tags: list, ant, directory

I have a directory with plenty of moduls in it.

Looks like:

```
C: 

|--Project 

      |----files

            |----Modul1
                    |----FoldersinModuls
            |----Modul2
                    |----FoldersinModuls
            |----Modul3
                    |----FoldersinModuls
            |----Modul4
                    |----FoldersinModuls
```

I need a list like this: 
Modul1,Modul2,Modul3,Modul4

But the only thing I get is: `C:\Project\files\Modul1,C:\Project\files\Modul2,C:\Project\files\Modul3,C:\Project\files\Modul4`

```
<dirset id="list.moduls" dir="${basedir}" includes="*" excludes=".folder">
</dirset>
<pathconvert pathsep="," property="list.of.moduls" refid="list.moduls">
<mapper type="identity"/> 
</pathconvert>  
<echo message="${list.of.moduls}"/>
```

Comment: I Finally solved it using this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176071/replacing-characters-in-ant-property 

> Answer --> In case you want a solution that does use Ant built-ins
> only, consider this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jayan i answered it by comment because i had to leave my workplace.

I Finally solved it using this answer:

[Replacing characters in Ant property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176071/replacing-characters-in-ant-property)

> Answer --> In case you want a solution that does use Ant built-ins
>   only, consider this:

It is btw the only method i found that worked. A direct generation/replacement (as i thought) is not possible.