# ANT remove blank spaces regexp

Tags: regex, ant, spaces, ant-contrib

I want to get the .doc file name and save it in the next property (`pdf.name`). Using regexp I want to remove all the blank spaces in the .doc file name and transform it from this:

```
NAME FILE.doc
```

To this:

```
NAMEFILE.pdf
```

This is my code:

```
<propertyregex override="yes" property="pdf.name" input="@{remoteDocToPdf}" 
     regexp="\.*([[^/]+$^\.]*)\.doc" select="\1.pdf" casesensitive="true" />
```

Comment: Does the `input` of `@{remoteDocToPdf}` carry an absolute path like `/var/run/myapp/NAME FILE.doc`, or just a filename like `NAME FILE.doc`?

Comment: Hi zb226, it's just filename.  NAME FILE XXX XXX.doc

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176071/replacing-characters-in-ant-property

Answer (score 1):

If `@{remoteDocToPdf}` only carries a filename and not an absolute path, you can remove the spaces in the filename by adding this directive after the one you posted:

```
<propertyregex override="yes" property="pdf.name" input="${pdf.name}"
    regexp=" " replace="" global="true" />
```

It's not possible to delete the spaces and do the `.doc` -> `.pdf` transformation in one go, since you can only either specify `select` or `replace` per `<propertyregex...`.

**Edit 1:** I missed adding `global="true"` to the above, so only the first space would have been replaced (according to the [documentation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html), at least).

**Edit 2:** A note on the `<propertyregex...` you've posted - I'm pretty sure that the regular expression `\.*([[^/]+$^\.]*)\.doc` is not really what you want, even though it may seem to work as intended. From your comment I'm guessing that all you want to do is replace `.doc` with `.pdf`. In that case, please use this instead:

```
<propertyregex override="yes" property="pdf.name" input="@{remoteDocToPdf}" 
    regexp="\.doc$" replace=".pdf" />
```

If you'd like to read up on regular expressions, I can recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Ant [resources](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html) to do this.  This might be close to what you need:

```
<loadresource property="pdf.name">
    <string value="${remoteDocToPdf}" />
    <filterchain>
        <deletecharacters chars=" " />
        <replaceregex pattern=".doc$" replace=".pdf" />
    </filterchain>
</loadresource>
```

The work is being done by the [filterchain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) comprised of two filters: one that removes spaces, and one that changes the file extension.