# ReplaceRegex Function not doing the job

Tags: regex, ant, properties, boost-regex, regex-greedy

I want to edit this line of input and add some more values to the Product_A Key.

```
 input="CSDT_FLAG_PRODUCT_FF_FWUIDS=Product_A:45223423;Product_PD:4;Product_CD:345345,22454;Product_F:3423"
```

I have the below ant replaceregex line.

```
replaceregexp file="../cms-distribution/src/main/properties/editorial/common/csdtflags.properties" flags="s" match="Product_A:([^\.]*)([;])?" replace="Product_A:,${uid}\1" byline="true"/>
```

This does the job except the results produced :

```
CSDT_FLAG_PRODUCT_FF_FWUIDS=Product_A:+,42e8140a-79ce-4bda-b64a-539bc4a17dbb+,80ab7183-715d-471b-8ae0-b527d2597b06+,......
```

It inserts a + symbol from nowhere and secondly it replaces the original value that was present in Product_A. I want to append to the original value with a comma. How do i do this? 
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a thing about ant and how it handles regex but I think the problem relies on the regex. You have an string

```
"CSDT_FLAG_PRODUCT_FF_FWUIDS=Product_A:45223423;Product_PD:4;Product_CD:345345,22454;Product_F:3423"
```

and a regex

```
/Product_A:([^\.]*)([;])?/
```

The `;` matches till the last appearance of the character `;`, thus not matching only the value under **Product_A**, see it yourself [here](http://rubular.com/r/0Kw9hvJHla).

However, if you now that the value at **Product_A** key will always be an 8 digit string you can use this regex:

```
/Product_A:(.{8});/
```

The match group inside the `()` will capture the code, this is as much as I can help you, maybe this answer [Replacing characters in Ant property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176071/replacing-characters-in-ant-property) helps.