# Parsing xml property to ant-build.xml file

Tags: java, xml, ant, xml-parsing, antbuilder

I have a xml file "versionreferance.xml". below is the coding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Update "revision" value to -1 when the next build is intended to have its revision as 0. This needs to be done for patch/release builds-->
<BuildVersions>
  <property name="major" value="1" />
  <property name="minor" value="0" />
  <property name="patch" value="0" />
  <property name="revision" value="93" />
</BuildVersions>
```

The other is my ant-build.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="xmlproperty-demo" default="init">
    <xmlproperty file="versionreferance.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
        <echo>Major : ${BuildVersions.major}</echo>
        <echo>Minor : ${BuildVersions.minor}</echo>
        <echo>Patch : ${BuildVersions.patch}</echo>
        <echo>Revision : ${BuildVersions.revision}</echo>
</project>
```

I am not getting the value in the output.

I want to get the path path dynamically of versionReference.xml , which will be in different place than antbuild.xml

**Development\Build\VersionReference.xml**

**Development\Src\JAAS API\antbuild.xml**

It should be dynamically. I am able to get the values form below code. But it's not dynamic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="xmlproperty-demo" default="init">
    <xmlproperty file="C:\\Development\\Build\\versionreferance.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
        <echo>Major : ${BuildVersions.major}</echo>
        <echo>Minor : ${BuildVersions.minor}</echo>
        <echo>Patch : ${BuildVersions.patch}</echo>
        <echo>Revision : ${BuildVersions.revision}</echo>
</project>
```

I want to get the values only in this format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Update "revision" value to -1 when the next build is intended to have its revision as 0.     This needs to be done for patch/release builds-->
<BuildVersions>
  <property name="major" value="1" />
  <property name="minor" value="0" />
  <property name="patch" value="0" />
  <property name="revision" value="93" />
</BuildVersions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **VersionReference.xml** is going to be exactly where you mentioned in your question corresponding to your **antbuild.xml**.

I would suggest you to change your Absolute Path (as mentioned in question) with **"..\..\Build\VersionReference.xml"** which corresponds to the basedir="." in your project

This should work fine.

And considering your string format requirement.

I think the default comma(,) seperated value can then be replaced by dot(.) or manipulated as per your requirement by the following syntax

```
<propertyregex property="propB"
               input="${propA}"
               regexp=","
               replace="."
               global="true" />
```

Please find more info on this link : 
[Replacing characters in Ant property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176071/replacing-characters-in-ant-property)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using the free, third-party [XmlTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) library:

### build.xml

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" />
<xmltask>
    <fileset file="versionreferance.xml"/>
    <copy path="/BuildVersions/property[@name = 'major']/@value" property="BuildVersions.major"/>
    <copy path="/BuildVersions/property[@name = 'minor']/@value" property="BuildVersions.minor"/>
    <copy path="/BuildVersions/property[@name = 'patch']/@value" property="BuildVersions.patch"/>
    <copy path="/BuildVersions/property[@name = 'revision']/@value" property="BuildVersions.revision"/>
</xmltask>

<echo>Major : ${BuildVersions.major}</echo>
<echo>Minor : ${BuildVersions.minor}</echo>
<echo>Patch : ${BuildVersions.patch}</echo>
<echo>Revision : ${BuildVersions.revision}</echo>
```

### Output

```
run:
     [echo] Major : 1
     [echo] Minor : 0
     [echo] Patch : 0
     [echo] Revision : 93
```

Comment: @Kaushalpanchal42 you will probably need to add a `<classpath>` to the `taskdef` pointing to the xmltask JAR file.

Comment: @Chad Nouis How can I Iterate the same root commands with different values from build.xml??

Answer (score 1):

If you add `<echoproperties/>` after the `<xmlproperty>` line you should see the properties are loaded but not as you expect. They will be something like:

```
BuildVersions.property=,,,
BuildVersions.property.name=major,minor,patch,revision
BuildVersions.property.value=1,0,0,93
```

This is because the properties are based off the node names, and in your case you have four instances of a "property" child node that are not unique. Your best bet may be to change the xml such as:

```
<BuildVersions>
    <major>1</major>
    ....
</BuildVersions>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say `xmlproperty` with `collapseAttributes="true"` on xml file, it will flatten nested elements.

Details: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html

So just saying `${BuildVersions.major}` doesn't give or print value as 1. Since you have same named xml element 'prooerty' you won't be able to get single propertie's value

For eg, in your case `${BuildVersions.property.name}` will print '`major,minor,patch,revision`'

Either you can redesign your versionreferance.xml to respect xmlproperty to work . Or you can make it as property file & say `<property file="your.properties.file"/>` & access them as normal properties!