# Ant: How to xml-escape property values when copying xml files with "filtering"

Tags: xml, ant

This issue came up recently. I've been using ant for eons and know I could 'hack around' this issue, but thought to ask: does ant offer an elegant solution for this usecase?

**Problem**

When I use ant to copy xml files and "populate values" using the "filtering" attribute, how can I make it automatically escape ampersands (and other xml 'special characters')?

**Context**

Rather than have installers/implementers hand-edit all the various application-server specific configuration files, we have them edit a 'build.properties' files in our application's root directory. Ant copies a pre-configured 'source' version of the file to a 'target' directory whilst populating values from the properties files

1) Build.properties has this value:

```
JDBC_PASSWORD=smith&wesson
```

2) "Source" configuration file has this element:

```
  <local-tx-datasource>
    ...
    <password>@JDBC_PASSWORD@</password>
    ...
  </local-tx-datasource>
```

3) Ant copies the xml files from the 'source' configuration directory and populates the 'JDBC_PASSWORD' (among others properties) with the 'filtering' attribute:

```
<copy todir="${appserver.home.dir}" filtering="yes">
   <fileset dir="${appserver.conf.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.xml"/>
   </fileset>
</copy>
```

4) Because the property has an ampersand, the resulting 'target' xml file is invalid. (The '&' should be '&amp;')

```
  <local-tx-datasource>
    ...
    <password>smith&wesson</password>
    ...
  </local-tx-datasource>
```

**Desired Result**

Instead of 4, I would like this:

```
  <local-tx-datasource>
    ...
    <password>smith&amp;wesson</password>
    ...
  </local-tx-datasource>
```

**Additional**

I need to worry about the whole 'cast of characters', i.e. less-than, greater-than, etc., as well as the ampersand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've the same problem. How did you resolve yours? Did you write a custom encoder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JDBC_PASSWORD=smith&amp;wesson
```

will result in :

```
 <local-tx-datasource>
  <password>smith&amp;wesson</password>
 </local-tx-datasource>
```

will get parsed as :

```
 <local-tx-datasource>
  <password>smith&wesson</password>
 </local-tx-datasource>
```

```
JDBC_PASSWORD=smith&amp;amp;wesson
```

will result in :

```
 <local-tx-datasource>
  <password>smith&amp;amp;wesson</password>
 </local-tx-datasource>
```

will get parsed as :

```
 <local-tx-datasource>
  <password>smith&amp;wesson</password>
 </local-tx-datasource>
```

Similar :

`less-than : &lt;`

`greater-than : &gt;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ant-Contrib task [URLEncode](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/urlencode.html) (Yes, it says **Foreach** on the heading, but that's only to throw ***the heat*** off the trail.).

You can use that to make sure that any values you're passing via `<filterset/>` to a tokenized XML file is correctly formatted.

You'll have to define a `<taskdef/>` for the Ant-Contrib tasks and include the Ant Contrib jar.

Comment: URL encoding differs from XML encoding. This is the right direction, I believe as one would need a custom encoder.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't replacing an attribute value, you can always use a [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section instead.  Ampersand, less-than, etc. within the CDATA don't need to be entity escaped.

```
<local-tx-datasource>
  ...
  <password><![CDATA[@JDBC_PASSWORD@]]></password>
  ...
</local-tx-datasource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting your question together with [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135833/276232) can get you what you want.

First, convert the property value:

```
<loadresource property="jdbc.password.escaped">
  <propertyresource name="jdbc.password"/>
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <replacestring from="&amp;" to="&amp;amp;"/><!-- note: double escape -->
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</loadresource>
```

Now, use the updated property value:

```
<filter token="JDBC_PASSWORD" value="${jdbc.password.escaped}" />

<copy todir="${appserver.home.dir}" filtering="yes">
<fileset dir="${appserver.conf.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.xml"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

You may have to adapt the above to suit your actual property names, etc. but that should get you going.