# Running ant script in bash script with command line parameters containing a dollar sign

Tags: bash, ant

I have a problem in passing a string containing a dollar sign to ant script.

In tclist text file,

```
org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load$Test  testFile3
```

In bash script,

```
while read tcls tmethod
do

    echo ${tcls},${tmethod}
    ant -Dtcls="$tcls" -Dtmethods="$tmethod"

done < $tclist
```

In ant script,

```
<echo message="Run ${tcls}, ${tmethods}."/>
<junit haltonerror="false" haltonfailure="false" printsummary="true" fork="true">
    <test name="${tcls}" todir="${result.junit.dir}" methods="${tmethods}"/>
</junit>
```

bash echo message,

```
org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load$Test,testFile3
```

ant echo message,

```
[echo] Run org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load, testFile3.
```

The echo message shows that substring after the dollar sign disappears...
I'm stuck in this problem for hours. Is there any way to print the whole string?

**Update:**
A temporary remedy...
I couldn't find a reason for this, but I solved the problem.
I add "/" after "$" in tclist not to be removed in the ant script. Next, I use a sed expression in the ant script to replace "$/" with "$". A comment from here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151678/1900548) helps me come up with this idea. If anyone knows the exact reason for this problem, please let me know. Thanks.

In tclist text file,

```
org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load$/Test testFile3
```

In ant script,

```
<exec executable="sed" inputstring="${tcls}" outputproperty="tcls_after">
    <arg value="s/$\//$/g"/>
</exec>

<echo message="Run ${tcls_after}, ${tmethods}."/>
```

ant echo message,

```
[echo] Run org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load$Test, testFile3.
```

Comment: Try putting "echo $tcls" in your loop between "do" and "ant" to see if your "read" statement is working.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for comment. I added bash echo message. It seems that bash echo is working correctly...

Comment: I think the bash script is trying to substitute a value for $Test eventhough the value was quoted.  If you set variable value for Test, then run and see if that value gets appended to end of ...Load<your value>